# how can I set a breakpoint to get the async result in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

How can I set a breakpoint to get the async result in this scenario?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task Test()
{
    await GetAllUsers();
}

static async Task GetAllUsers()
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "api/v1/users");
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the end of the using statement in GetAllUsers() then the response value is:

Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

When I continue to step through the code I'm not clear on how I can get a handle to the final value.  Any suggestions on the code I can include to get a handle to the final return value?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `await` keyword near `GetAsync` function call. After fixing that, you will be able to see the result. (BP at end of `using`)

```
static async Task GetAllUsers()
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "api/v1/users");
    }
}
```